# XML in Node.js (Using Javascript)

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I've got simulated XML data stored the hard disk (called simmedData.xml).  I've also got 'real' data (the 'real' data is dynamic) vended through a web endpoint (`http://localhost:8079/realData`).

The format of the XML documents are exactly the same, but I would like to 'merge' them into one endpoint available at `http://localhost:8080/mergedData`.

I want to use node.js to host the mergedData endpoint  -- Is there a simple way to merge these xml documents together when mergedData is requested?

For example:

**simmedData.xml**

```
<site:Tracks xmlns:site='http://mysite/site'>
  <site:track id='1' latitude='37.82091918923291' longitude='128.87375778822812' altitude='9753.6005859375' bearing='10.542624087704585' speedInKnots='454.6067199707031' />
  <site:track id='2' latitude='37.45048387959727' longitude='129.49111126654887' altitude='9144.0' bearing='190.90400586790983' speedInKnots='436.89837646484375' />
</site:Tracks>
```

**http://localhost:8079/realData**

```
<site:Tracks xmlns:site='http://mysite/site'>
  <site:track id='1001' latitude='39.82093291' longitude='128.87375722812' altitude='9753.60375' bearing='10.542704585' speedInKnots='454.6707031' />
  <site:track id='1002' latitude='39.387959727' longitude='129.4126654887' altitude='9144.0' bearing='90.90790983' speedInKnots='436.8984375' />
  <site:track id='1003' latitude='40.82093291' longitude='138.87375722812' altitude='9753.5' bearing='10.542704585' speedInKnots='454.6707031' />
  <site:track id='1004' latitude='40.387959727' longitude='139.4126654887' altitude='9124.0' bearing='90.90790983' speedInKnots='436.8984375' />
</site:Tracks>
```

**http://localhost:8080/mergedData**

```
<site:Tracks xmlns:site='http://mysite/site'>
  <site:track id='1' latitude='37.82091918923291' longitude='128.87375778822812' altitude='9753.6005859375' bearing='10.542624087704585' speedInKnots='454.6067199707031' />
  <site:track id='2' latitude='37.45048387959727' longitude='129.49111126654887' altitude='9144.0' bearing='190.90400586790983' speedInKnots='436.89837646484375' />
  <site:track id='1001' latitude='39.82093291' longitude='128.87375722812' altitude='9753.60375' bearing='10.542704585' speedInKnots='454.6707031' />
  <site:track id='1002' latitude='39.387959727' longitude='129.4126654887' altitude='9144.0' bearing='90.90790983' speedInKnots='436.8984375' />
  <site:track id='1003' latitude='40.82093291' longitude='138.87375722812' altitude='9753.5' bearing='10.542704585' speedInKnots='454.6707031' />
  <site:track id='1004' latitude='40.387959727' longitude='139.4126654887' altitude='9124.0' bearing='90.90790983' speedInKnots='436.8984375' />
</site:Tracks>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do any kind of intelligent "XML-aware" merge then you probably would be looking at an XML parser to do DOM manipulation or an XSLT transformer to run a stylesheet that would merge the two. I am sure there are libxml/libxslt wrappers for node:

- [XSLT for node.js](http://toolbox.no.de/packages/node_xslt)
- [XML Parsers for node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240577/node-js-library-implementing-w3c-xml-dom)

I recently answered a question here at SO about [XML merge with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477524/how-to-concatenate-two-or-more-xml-files-using-xslt-and-maintain-the-order/10523360#10523360) but if you just do a straightforward "append" then it will be much less trickier.